# Unable to see correlations using the "Corr.test "function

Tags: r

So, I'm SUPER new with R and frequently find myself getting tripped up by the most basic functions. Right now, I have a data frame of which contains 7 different variables that I want to view the correlation relationships. Most of the posts I've seen online talk about how to use the corr.test function (psych package) if using a dataframe, but I'm not sure how to just specify the variables I'm looking for. I keep getting error codes for the script below (keeping the variable names anonymous):

```
corr.test(mydatareg$V1, mydatareg$V2, mydatareg$V3, mydatareg$V4, mydatareg$V5, mydatareg$V6, mydatareg$V7, y = NULL, use = "pairwise", method="pearson", adjust="holm", alpha=.05, ci=TRUE, minlength=5)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe something like `corr.test(mydatareg[,1:7])`

Comment: @G5W, this worked! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.